# menu item cannot be clicked to open an external link

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Reference Website: http://www.hakimnaturalhealth.com.au/

I am unable to click on the menu item 'Online Booking' which I have set href to open to an external link. This is done through wordpress menu management.

The codes for this menu item is;

```
<li id="menu-item-581" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-581 active"><a href="http://hakim-natural-health.cliniko.com/bookings#service">Online Booking</a></li>
```

The CSS;

```
ul#nav li {float: none; text-align: right;}
```

It is worth to note the other menu items are assigned to sections within the one page.

Appreciate any ideas :)

Comment: It is a javascript issue, please post the relevant code.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

it is a javascript problem but you can get the same functionality by replacing the following code

```
<a title="a" href="http://hakim-natural-health.cliniko.com/bookings#service">Online Booking</a>
```

**with**

```
<a title="a" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://hakim-natural-health.cliniko.com/bookings#service'">Online Booking</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since I am using wordpress, and this menu is generated from the menu editor, which file should I edit for this? Because there's no way to edit the html directly, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that based on your HTML menu, that you have a javascript function which is imposed on the menu. When clicking the `<li>` menu item the script prevents redirection of the page because it is looking for something internal to your site.

[image: JS error]